# Issue with site selection box in User Reputation Leagues page

Tags: bug, reputation-leagues

I was viewing [the User Reputation League page for MSE](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/quarter/meta/2021-07-01?sort=totalreputation) (to look at the list of big timers here), where I became aware of a minor but frustrating flaw.  When I change the value of the select box to view the stats for a different site, for random sites, after the page reloads, the select box will show Stack Overflow.  The problem with that is that if I actually want to see SO, I can't because it's already "selected".

Comment: Likely a bug because it's not supposed to be like that: only some sites are affected. For example, Server Fault correctly updates the select value. Initial hunch is that there is a discrepancy between values in the select options and whatever the script that updates the select expects.

Comment: Actually, upon further inspection, it's worse - the page comes pre-rendered, and the selected value is set server-side, so something got botched there. Definitely a bug, though I can throw a userscript together :)

Comment: FYI, it doesn't always select Stack Overflow. Looks like most items indeed make it select SO, but not all of them. For example, if you select English Language and Usage, it goes to Physical Fitness.

Comment: @41686d6564 echo is strong here :) Seems like SE has something botched server-side as the select comes with an already selected value - nothing on the page does that, the `selected="selected"` is set on the option even before the page is served.

Comment: Most change to SO. Those that don't: the trilogy and MSE direct to themselves. ELL → Physical Fitness. Electrical Engineering → Signal Processing. Android → Christianity. Travel → SO Portuguese. Personal Finance → Project Management. M&TV → elementaryOS. Philosophy → Pets. Board&Card Games → Bible Hermeneutics. French → Earth Science. Spanish → CiviCRM. CompSci → Law. Chinese → Portuguese. Sports → Motor Vehicles. Poker → Hardware Recommendations